# How to Embed Stackexchange Account Metrics into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, badge, stackexchange

How can I embed Stackexchange reputation scores and badge counts into my Wordpress blog? I want to show on my blog a small table with accounts as rows and columns consisting of rep scores and badge counts. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Use the [API](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/api), Luke ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a testing code I already had for consuming [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Print SE-API Results as Admin Notice
 */

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'b5f_consume_se_api' );

function b5f_consume_se_api() 
{
    $user = '1417894';
    $page_size = '&pagesize=3';
    $order = '&order=desc';
    $sort = '&sort=votes';

    $so = wp_remote_get( 
        'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/'
        . $user
        . '/answers?site=stackexchange'
        . $page_size . $order . $sort ,     
        array(
            'timeout'     => 120, 
            'httpversion' => '1.1' 
        ) 
    );

    if ( $so['response']['code'] == '200' )
    {
        $so_array = json_decode( $so['body'], true );
        var_dump( $so_array['items'] );
    }
}
```

[This is the URL](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1417894/answers?site=stackoverflow&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=votes) being consulted and its JSON result. It returns the last 3 answers from the OP, sorted by votes (descending).

Check the docs and adapt everything to suit your needs.

Answer (score 11):

You could you use User Flair for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 0):

Add a text widget your sidebar and paste your [flair HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417894/Chernoff/flair) in it.